# Stack checkboxes to the right column and label to the left using CSS grid

Tags: html, css, jsx, css-grid

*I'm having trouble getting the checkboxes to stack properly on top of each other in their own grid column*. I'm using ReactQL (jsx) so I don't think it will show up properly in the code-snippet editor. Floats aren't useful here.

```css
/* checkboxes */

.section__checkboxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}

.description {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.checkbox {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.choice {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div className={cn (css.section__checkboxes, css.section_wrapper)}>
  <label className={css.description} htmlFor="checkbox_2">email notifications</label>

  <input id="checkbox_2_1" name="checkbox_2_1" className={css.checkbox} type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label className={css.choice} htmlFor="checkbox_2_1">new direct messages</label>
  <input id="checkbox_2_2" name="checkbox_2_2" className={css.checkbox} type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label className={css.choice} htmlFor="checkbox_2_2">new user signups</label>
  <input id="checkbox_2_3" name="checkbox_2_3" className={css.checkbox} type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label className={css.choice} htmlFor="checkbox_2_3">new uploads</label>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're putting **all** the elements on the same grid-row. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grid-row: span 3` for the `description` to *span* the rows in the left. If you want to preserve the current markup, you can and add `grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 2fr`. See demo below:

```css
.section__checkboxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}

.description {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div class="section__checkboxes section_wrapper">
  <label class="description" for="checkbox_2">email notifications</label>
  <input id="checkbox_2_1" name="checkbox_2_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label class="choice" for="checkbox_2_1">new direct messages</label>
  <input id="checkbox_2_2" name="checkbox_2_2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label class="choice" for="checkbox_2_2">new user signups</label>
  <input id="checkbox_2_3" name="checkbox_2_3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label class="choice" for="checkbox_2_3">new uploads</label>
</div>
```

If you'd change your markup and wrap the `label` and `checkbox`es together, you can do it like this:

```css
.section__checkboxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}

.description {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div class="section__checkboxes section_wrapper">
  <label class="description" for="checkbox_2">email notifications</label>
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox_2_1" name="checkbox_2_1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="checkbox_2_1">new direct messages</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox_2_2" name="checkbox_2_2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="checkbox_2_2">new user signups</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="checkbox_2_3" name="checkbox_2_3" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="checkbox_2_3">new uploads</label>
  </div>
</div>
```